# Swift sets rootViewController in AppDelegate with delay

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, appdelegate

I want to set initial ViewController in AppDelegate. As:

```
 if jsonResult["result"]!.intValue == 1 {
     let entryPoint: UITabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
     self.window?.rootViewController = entryPoint
} else {
     let entryPoint: WelcomeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeController") as! WelcomeController
     self.window?.rootViewController = entryPoint
}
```

it works, but at first it opens the view controller which I set as initial in my storyboard and just later it switches programmatically.

So, how can I switch my controller directly without showing my first controller? What I do wrong?

Comment: The issue is (at least appears to be since we don't have a lot of detail here) that you are waiting for a JSON payload to be received and parsed prior to loading the UI. What happens if the user has not internet connection? What if the connection is incredibly slow/spotty?

I would spend some time rethinking the flow of the app. Are these views really the first views the user should see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to galois's comment:

...and what happens if there *is* no result due to a completed request with an error? Force-unwrapping the result with `!` would crash your app. You should look into Grand Central Dispatch calls. Start an asynchronous call to get your JSON with a callback on the main thread to update your UI upon completion and let your UI load into some "waiting" state directly while it waits in the background for the JSON.

Comment: I did `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in` and inside of it I'm loading JSON and do what I need to do. Yes, it works, but partly. Now it loads faster, but it shows the initial view controller from the storyboard for half a second. I want to ignore it at all